# expected ';' in JSX constructor definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  http.getProducts();

}
```

I am in the process of learning react, currently I am trying to call a function getProducts() from a separate file, but, when I make this constructor, I get an error asking for a ';' in between the opening bracket and the closing parenthesis after props, im not too sure as to why. Here is the error I am getting

[image: browser]

Comment: `constructor(props) {` has to be put in side a `class` body. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes. This has nothing to do with React or JSX.

Comment: Make sure your App.js is a class component for using a constructor.

Comment: Ahhh it was a missing bracket, thanks guys!